# Fast pairwise simple linear regression between variables in a data frame

Tags: r, performance, regression, linear-regression, lm

I have seen pairwise or general paired simple linear regression many times on Stack Overflow. Here is a toy dataset for this kind of problem.

```
set.seed(0)
X <- matrix(runif(100), 100, 5, dimnames = list(1:100, LETTERS[1:5]))
b <- c(1, 0.7, 1.3, 2.9, -2)
dat <- X * b[col(X)] + matrix(rnorm(100 * 5, 0, 0.1), 100, 5)
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)
pairs(dat)
```

[image]

So basically we want to compute 5 * 4 = 20 regression lines:

```
-----  A ~ B  A ~ C  A ~ D  A ~ E
B ~ A  -----  B ~ C  B ~ D  B ~ E
C ~ A  C ~ B  -----  C ~ D  C ~ E
D ~ A  D ~ B  D ~ C  -----  D ~ E
E ~ A  E ~ B  E ~ C  E ~ D  -----
```

Here is a *poor man's* strategy:

```
poor <- function (dat) {
  n <- nrow(dat)
  p <- ncol(dat)
  ## all formulae
  LHS <- rep(colnames(dat), p)
  RHS <- rep(colnames(dat), each = p)
  ## function to fit and summarize a single model
  fitmodel <- function (LHS, RHS) {
    if (RHS == LHS) {
      z <- data.frame("LHS" = LHS, "RHS" = RHS,
                      "alpha" = 0,
                      "beta" = 1,
                      "beta.se" = 0,
                      "beta.tv" = Inf,
                      "beta.pv" = 0,
                      "sig" = 0,
                      "R2" = 1,
                      "F.fv" = Inf,
                      "F.pv" = 0,
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      } else {
      result <- summary(lm(reformulate(RHS, LHS), data = dat))
      z <- data.frame("LHS" = LHS, "RHS" = RHS,
                      "alpha" = result$coefficients[1, 1],
                      "beta" = result$coefficients[2, 1],
                      "beta.se" = result$coefficients[2, 2],
                      "beta.tv" = result$coefficients[2, 3],
                      "beta.pv" = result$coefficients[2, 4],
                      "sig" = result$sigma,
                      "R2" = result$r.squared,
                      "F.fv" = result$fstatistic[[1]],
                      "F.pv" = pf(result$fstatistic[[1]], 1, n - 2, lower.tail = FALSE),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        }
      z
      }
  ## loop through all models
  do.call("rbind.data.frame", c(Map(fitmodel, LHS, RHS),
                                list(make.row.names = FALSE,
                                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
  }
```

The logic is clear: get all pairs, construct the model formula (`reformulate`), fit a regression (`lm`), do a summary `summary`, return all statistics and `rbind` them to be a data frame.

OK, fine, but what if there are `p` variables? We then need to do `p * (p - 1)` regressions!

An immediate improvement I could think of, is [Fitting a linear model with multiple LHS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39262534/4891738). For example, the first column of that formula matrix is merged to

```
cbind(B, C, D, E) ~ A
```

This reduces the number of regression from `p * (p - 1)` to `p`.

But we can definitely do even better without using `lm` and `summary`. Here is my previous attempt: [Is there a fast estimation of simple regression (a regression line with only intercept and slope)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40141738/4891738). It is fast because it uses covariance between variables for estimation, like solving the [normal equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalEquation.html). But the `simpleLM` function there is pretty limited:

1. it needs to compute residual vectors to estimate residual standard error, which is a performance bottleneck;
2. it doesn't support multiple LHS, so it needs be called `p * (p - 1)` times in pairwise regression settings).

Can we generalize it for fast pairwise regression, by writing a function `pairwise_simpleLM`?

---

### General paired simple linear regression

A more useful variation of the above pairwise regression is the general paired regression between a set of LHS variables and a set of RHS variables.

**Example 1**

Fit paired regression between LHS variables `A`, `B`, `C` and RHS variables `D`, `E`, that is, fit 6 simple linear regression lines:

```
A ~ D  A ~ E
B ~ D  B ~ E
C ~ D  C ~ E
```

**Example 2**

Fit a simple linear regression with multiple LHS variables to a particular RHS variable, say: `cbind(A, B, C, D) ~ E`.

**Example 3**

Fit a simple linear regression with a particular LHS variable, and a set of RHS variables one at a time, for example:

```
A ~ B  A ~ C  A ~ D  A ~ E
```

Can we also have a fast function `general_paired_simpleLM` for this?

---

**Caution**

1. All variables must be numeric; factors are not allowed or pairwise regression makes no sense.
2. Weighted regression is not discussed, as variance-covariance method is not justified in that case.

Comment: There is a well-established equivalence between pairwise simple linear regression and pairwise correlation test. The former computes a bundle of things, but the latter focuses on correlation coefficient and p-value of the correlation. In R, `psych::corr.test` and `Hmisc::rcorr` can perform pairwise correlation test. In particular, they can do pairwise `NA` removal at presence of missing data. While my `pairwise_simpleLM` and `general_paired_simpleLM` can be used for correlation test (see `"beta.pv" `column for p-values), it can not handle pairwise `NA` removal.

Comment: `pairwise_simpleLM` and `general_paired_simpleLM` at the moment can not deal with `NA`. This requires implementing the whole function in C / C++. In future I would enhance them for such capability. In C / C++ implementation, it is also possible to use a more numerically stable method for computing covariance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Some statistical result / background

[image]

(Link in the picture: [Function to calculate R2 (R-squared) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40901487/4891738))

---

#### Computational details

Computations involved here is basically the computation of the variance-covariance matrix. Once we have it, results for all pairwise regression is just element-wise matrix arithmetic.

The variance-covariance matrix can be obtained by R function `cov`, but functions below [compute it manually using `crossprod`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40406382/4891738). The advantage is that it can obviously benefit from an optimized BLAS library if you have it. Be aware that significant amount of simplification is made in this way. R function `cov` has argument `use` which allows handling `NA`, but `crossprod` does not. I am assuming that your `dat` has no missing values at all! If you do have missing values, remove them yourself with `na.omit(dat)`.

The initial `as.matrix` that converts a data frame to a matrix might be an overhead. In principle if I code everything up in C / C++, I can eliminate this coercion. And in fact, many element-wise matrix matrix arithmetic can be merged into a single loop-nest. However, I really bother doing this at the moment (as I have no time).

Some people may argue that the format of the final return is inconvenient. There could be other format:

1. a list of data frames, each giving the result of the regression for a particular LHS variable;
2. a list of data frames, each giving the result of the regression for a particular RHS variable.

This is really opinion-based. Anyway, you can always do a `split.data.frame` by "LHS" column or "RHS" column yourself on the data frame I return you.

---

#### R function `pairwise_simpleLM`

```
pairwise_simpleLM <- function (dat) {
  ## matrix and its dimension (n: numbeta.ser of data; p: numbeta.ser of variables)
  dat <- as.matrix(dat)
  n <- nrow(dat)
  p <- ncol(dat)
  ## variable summary: mean, (unscaled) covariance and (unscaled) variance
  m <- colMeans(dat)
  V <- crossprod(dat) - tcrossprod(m * sqrt(n))
  d <- diag(V)
  ## R-squared (explained variance) and its complement
  R2 <- (V ^ 2) * tcrossprod(1 / d)
  R2_complement <- 1 - R2
  R2_complement[seq.int(from = 1, by = p + 1, length = p)] <- 0
  ## slope and intercept
  beta <- V * rep(1 / d, each = p)
  alpha <- m - beta * rep(m, each = p)
  ## residual sum of squares and standard error
  RSS <- R2_complement * d
  sig <- sqrt(RSS * (1 / (n - 2)))
  ## statistics for slope
  beta.se <- sig * rep(1 / sqrt(d), each = p)
  beta.tv <- beta / beta.se
  beta.pv <- 2 * pt(abs(beta.tv), n - 2, lower.tail = FALSE)
  ## F-statistic and p-value
  F.fv <- (n - 2) * R2 / R2_complement
  F.pv <- pf(F.fv, 1, n - 2, lower.tail = FALSE)
  ## export
  data.frame(LHS = rep(colnames(dat), times = p),
             RHS = rep(colnames(dat), each = p),
             alpha = c(alpha),
             beta = c(beta),
             beta.se = c(beta.se),
             beta.tv = c(beta.tv),
             beta.pv = c(beta.pv),
             sig = c(sig),
             R2 = c(R2),
             F.fv = c(F.fv),
             F.pv = c(F.pv),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  }
```

Let's compare the result on the toy dataset in the question.

```
oo <- poor(dat)
rr <- pairwise_simpleLM(dat)
all.equal(oo, rr)
#[1] TRUE
```

Let's see its output:

```
rr[1:3, ]
#  LHS RHS      alpha      beta    beta.se  beta.tv      beta.pv       sig
#1   A   A 0.00000000 1.0000000 0.00000000      Inf 0.000000e+00 0.0000000
#2   B   A 0.05550367 0.6206434 0.04456744 13.92594 5.796437e-25 0.1252402
#3   C   A 0.05809455 1.2215173 0.04790027 25.50126 4.731618e-45 0.1346059
#         R2     F.fv         F.pv
#1 1.0000000      Inf 0.000000e+00
#2 0.6643051 193.9317 5.796437e-25
#3 0.8690390 650.3142 4.731618e-45
```

When we have the same LHS and RHS, regression is meaningless hence intercept is 0, slope is 1, etc.

What about speed? Still using this toy example:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark("poor_man's" = poor(dat), "fast" = pairwise_simpleLM(dat))
#Unit: milliseconds
#       expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max
# poor_man's 127.270928 129.060515 137.813875 133.390722 139.029912 216.24995
#       fast   2.732184   3.025217   3.381613   3.134832   3.313079  10.48108
```

The gap is going be increasingly wider as we have more variables. For example, with 10 variables we have:

```
set.seed(0)
X <- matrix(runif(100), 100, 10, dimnames = list(1:100, LETTERS[1:10]))
b <- runif(10)
DAT <- X * b[col(X)] + matrix(rnorm(100 * 10, 0, 0.1), 100, 10)
DAT <- as.data.frame(DAT)
microbenchmark("poor_man's" = poor(DAT), "fast" = pairwise_simpleLM(DAT))
#Unit: milliseconds
#       expr        min         lq       mean     median        uq        max
# poor_man's 548.949161 551.746631 573.009665 556.307448 564.28355 801.645501
#       fast   3.365772   3.578448   3.721131   3.621229   3.77749   6.791786
```

---

#### R function `general_paired_simpleLM`

```
general_paired_simpleLM <- function (dat_LHS, dat_RHS) {
  ## matrix and its dimension (n: numbeta.ser of data; p: numbeta.ser of variables)
  dat_LHS <- as.matrix(dat_LHS)
  dat_RHS <- as.matrix(dat_RHS)
  if (nrow(dat_LHS) != nrow(dat_RHS)) stop("'dat_LHS' and 'dat_RHS' don't have same number of rows!")
  n <- nrow(dat_LHS)
  pl <- ncol(dat_LHS)
  pr <- ncol(dat_RHS)
  ## variable summary: mean, (unscaled) covariance and (unscaled) variance
  ml <- colMeans(dat_LHS)
  mr <- colMeans(dat_RHS)
  vl <- colSums(dat_LHS ^ 2) - ml * ml * n
  vr <- colSums(dat_RHS ^ 2) - mr * mr * n
  ##V <- crossprod(dat - rep(m, each = n))  ## cov(u, v) = E[(u - E[u])(v - E[v])]
  V <- crossprod(dat_LHS, dat_RHS) - tcrossprod(ml * sqrt(n), mr * sqrt(n))  ## cov(u, v) = E[uv] - E{u]E[v]
  ## R-squared (explained variance) and its complement
  R2 <- (V ^ 2) * tcrossprod(1 / vl, 1 / vr)
  R2_complement <- 1 - R2
  ## slope and intercept
  beta <- V * rep(1 / vr, each = pl)
  alpha <- ml - beta * rep(mr, each = pl)
  ## residual sum of squares and standard error
  RSS <- R2_complement * vl
  sig <- sqrt(RSS * (1 / (n - 2)))
  ## statistics for slope
  beta.se <- sig * rep(1 / sqrt(vr), each = pl)
  beta.tv <- beta / beta.se
  beta.pv <- 2 * pt(abs(beta.tv), n - 2, lower.tail = FALSE)
  ## F-statistic and p-value
  F.fv <- (n - 2) * R2 / R2_complement
  F.pv <- pf(F.fv, 1, n - 2, lower.tail = FALSE)
  ## export
  data.frame(LHS = rep(colnames(dat_LHS), times = pr),
             RHS = rep(colnames(dat_RHS), each = pl),
             alpha = c(alpha),
             beta = c(beta),
             beta.se = c(beta.se),
             beta.tv = c(beta.tv),
             beta.pv = c(beta.pv),
             sig = c(sig),
             R2 = c(R2),
             F.fv = c(F.fv),
             F.pv = c(F.pv),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  }
```

Apply this to **Example 1** in the question.

```
general_paired_simpleLM(dat[1:3], dat[4:5])
#  LHS RHS        alpha       beta    beta.se   beta.tv      beta.pv        sig
#1   A   D -0.009212582  0.3450939 0.01171768  29.45071 1.772671e-50 0.09044509
#2   B   D  0.012474593  0.2389177 0.01420516  16.81908 1.201421e-30 0.10964516
#3   C   D -0.005958236  0.4565443 0.01397619  32.66585 1.749650e-54 0.10787785
#4   A   E  0.008650812 -0.4798639 0.01963404 -24.44040 1.738263e-43 0.10656866
#5   B   E  0.012738403 -0.3437776 0.01949488 -17.63426 3.636655e-32 0.10581331
#6   C   E  0.009068106 -0.6430553 0.02183128 -29.45569 1.746439e-50 0.11849472
#         R2      F.fv         F.pv
#1 0.8984818  867.3441 1.772671e-50
#2 0.7427021  282.8815 1.201421e-30
#3 0.9158840 1067.0579 1.749650e-54
#4 0.8590604  597.3333 1.738263e-43
#5 0.7603718  310.9670 3.636655e-32
#6 0.8985126  867.6375 1.746439e-50
```

Apply this to **Example 2** in the question.

```
general_paired_simpleLM(dat[1:4], dat[5])
#  LHS RHS       alpha       beta    beta.se   beta.tv      beta.pv       sig
#1   A   E 0.008650812 -0.4798639 0.01963404 -24.44040 1.738263e-43 0.1065687
#2   B   E 0.012738403 -0.3437776 0.01949488 -17.63426 3.636655e-32 0.1058133
#3   C   E 0.009068106 -0.6430553 0.02183128 -29.45569 1.746439e-50 0.1184947
#4   D   E 0.066190196 -1.3767586 0.03597657 -38.26820 9.828853e-61 0.1952718
#         R2      F.fv         F.pv
#1 0.8590604  597.3333 1.738263e-43
#2 0.7603718  310.9670 3.636655e-32
#3 0.8985126  867.6375 1.746439e-50
#4 0.9372782 1464.4551 9.828853e-61
```

Apply this to **Example 3** in the question.

```
general_paired_simpleLM(dat[1], dat[2:5])
#  LHS RHS        alpha       beta    beta.se   beta.tv      beta.pv        sig
#1   A   B  0.112229318  1.0703491 0.07686011  13.92594 5.796437e-25 0.16446951
#2   A   C  0.025628210  0.7114422 0.02789832  25.50126 4.731618e-45 0.10272687
#3   A   D -0.009212582  0.3450939 0.01171768  29.45071 1.772671e-50 0.09044509
#4   A   E  0.008650812 -0.4798639 0.01963404 -24.44040 1.738263e-43 0.10656866
#         R2     F.fv         F.pv
#1 0.6643051 193.9317 5.796437e-25
#2 0.8690390 650.3142 4.731618e-45
#3 0.8984818 867.3441 1.772671e-50
#4 0.8590604 597.3333 1.738263e-43
```

We can even just do a simple linear regression between two variables:

```
general_paired_simpleLM(dat[1], dat[2])
#  LHS RHS     alpha     beta    beta.se  beta.tv      beta.pv       sig
#1   A   B 0.1122293 1.070349 0.07686011 13.92594 5.796437e-25 0.1644695
#         R2     F.fv         F.pv
#1 0.6643051 193.9317 5.796437e-25
```

This means that the `simpleLM` function in is now obsolete.

---

**Appendix: Markdown (needs MathJax support) fot the picture**

```
Denote our variables by $x_1$, $x_2$, etc, a pairwise simple linear regression takes the form $$x_i = \alpha_{ij} + \beta_{ij}x_j$$ where $\alpha_{ij}$ and $\beta_{ij}$ is the intercept and the slope of $x_i \sim x_j$, respectively. We also denote $m_i$ and $v_i$ as the sample mean and **unscaled** sample variance of $x_i$. Here, the unscaled variance is just the sum of squares without dividing by sample size, that is $v_i = \sum_{k = 1}^n(x_{ik} - m_i)^2 = (\sum_{k = 1}^nx_{ik}^2) - n m_i^2$. We also denote $V_{ij}$ as the **unscaled** covariance between $x_i$ and $x_j$: $V_{ij} = \sum_{k = 1}^n(x_{ik} - m_i)(x_{jk} - m_j)$ = $(\sum_{k = 1}^nx_{ik}x_{jk}) - nm_im_j$.

Using the results for a simple linear regression given in [Function to calculate R2 (R-squared) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40901487/4891738), we have $$\beta_{ij} = V_{ij} \ / \ v_j,\quad \alpha_{ij} = m_i - \beta_{ij}m_j,\quad r_{ij}^2 = V_{ij}^2 \ / \ (v_iv_j),$$ where $r_{ij}^2$ is the R-squared. Knowing $r_{ij}^2 = RSS_{ij} \ / \ TSS_{ij}$ where $RSS_{ij}$ and $TSS_{ij} = v_i$ are residual sum of squares and total sum of squares of $x_i \sim x_j$, we can derive $RSS_{ij}$ and residual standard error $\sigma_{ij}$ **without actually computing residuals**: $$RSS_{ij} = (1 - r_{ij}^2)v_i,\quad \sigma_{ij} = \sqrt{RSS_{ij} \ / \ (n - 2)}.$$

F-statistic $F_{ij}$ and associated p-value $p_{ij}^F$ can also be obtained from sum of squares: $$F_{ij} = \tfrac{(TSS_{ij} - RSS_{ij}) \ / \ 1}{RSS_{ij} \ / \ (n - 2)} = (n - 2) r_{ij}^2 \ / \ (1 - r_{ij}^2),\quad p_{ij}^F = 1 - \texttt{CDF_F}(F_{ij};\ 1,\ n - 2),$$ where $\texttt{CDF_F}$ denotes the CDF of F-distribution.

The only thing left is the standard error $e_{ij}$, t-statistic $t_{ij}$ and associated p-value $p_{ij}^t$ for $\beta_{ij}$, which are $$e_{ij} = \sigma_{ij} \ / \ \sqrt{v_i},\quad t_{ij} = \beta_{ij} \ / \ e_{ij},\quad p_{ij}^t = 2 * \texttt{CDF_t}(-|t_{ij}|; \ n - 2),$$ where $\texttt{CDF_t}$ denotes the CDF of t-distribution.
```