# R - Using apply only on specific columns

Tags: r, apply

I am using a package in R that fits a specific form of a regression model. However, unlike the base lm() function that permits the x and y to be separate objects, the function that I'm using requires them to be in the same dataframe.

My problem arises because I have a lot of variables that I want to regress on y independently. Therefore, I have a dataframe with 10 predictor variables (x1, x2... x10) and one criterion variable (y), 11 columns in total. I could use a for loop to run ten separate regressions, but I want to avoid it and use the apply function instead. However, if I call apply on my dataframe, in the last step it will regress y on y itself and I want to avoid this. Is there a function similar to apply which I could run and specify thiat I only want it to run 10 times and not 11, or is there another workaround to this problem?

Comment: [Fast pairwise simple linear regression between variables in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51953709/4891738). Look for function `general_paired_simpleLM`

Comment: Pass to apply an object without y. Nothing wrong with loops. If you pre-allocate your result object, things will go normally fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library( tidyverse )

xx <- c("disp", "hp", "drat", "wt")   # Names of predictor variables
y <- "mpg"                            # Name of response

str_c( y, xx, sep="~" ) %>%
  map( as.formula ) %>%               # Optional (see below)
  map( lm, data = mtcars )
```

`str_c` simply builds up formulas as strings (e.g., `"mpg~disp"`). While `lm` accepts strings directly, your particular regression model might not. If it requires an actual formula, you can convert strings to formulas using `as.formula` (Thanks for the suggestion, @J.Doe!). Other than that, simply replace `lm` with your particular model and `mtcars` with your data frame.

---

Here's the same solution using base R without any additional packages:

```
strs <- paste( y, xx, sep="~" )
strs <- lapply( strs, as.formula )    # Optional
lapply( strs, lm, data=mtcars )
```

Comment: Just `lapply(strs, lm, data=mtcars )` works doesn't it?

Comment: For `lm` yes (hence the #Optional comment), but it's not 100% clear what function the OP is using. He/she says it already differs from `lm` by requiring the input vectors to be in the same data frame. My guess is that it also takes a formula, rather than a string, that is contextually specific to that data frame input.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution worked, however, the optional line didn't convert the string expression to an object of a class "formula", but, instead, to an object of a class "call". Therefore, I changed 
    map(rlang::parse_expr) 
to 
    map(as.formula) and then everything worked.

Comment: Ah, yes. You're right! `rlang::expr` returns an expression, similar to `parse( text=x )`. You would need to follow it up with `eval` to evaluate the expression, which then produces a formula. Alternatively, your `as.formula` is a more elegant and compact solution! I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the builtin `anscombe` data frame having columns `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4`, `y1`, `y2`, `y3`, `y4` suppose we want to regress `y1` on each of `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4` separately.

First create a character vector of the names of the independent variables, `xnames`, and the use `lapply` to run the indicated `run_lm` over it.  That function pastes together the required formula and performs the `lm` returning an `"lm"` class object.  `L`, the result, is a list of such objects, one for each regression.

No packages are used.

```
xnames <- names(anscombe)[1:4]
run_lm <- function(nm) lm(paste("y1 ~", nm), anscombe)
L <- lapply(xnames, run_lm)
```

Alternately, this shorter version of `run_lm` would also work with the above `lapply` but the `Call:` output line is not as nice:

```
run_lm <- function(nm) lm(anscombe[c("y1", nm)])
```